# Route to user's page under the dynamic username path in MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some dynamic user route like

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            "UserNames", // Route name
            "{username}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "UserName" });
```

and under the **HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult UserName(string username)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = username;

           return RedirectToAction("Register","Account"); // Test...
        }
```

It is working fine.

But what I need is to get working the URL like

```
http:\\mywebsite.com\UserNameBob\MyGallery\1
http:\\mywebsite.com\UserNameBob\Profile
http:\\mywebsite.com\UserNameBob\MyFriends
```

How do I can archive it?

Any clu?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserNames", // Route name
    "{username}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "UserName", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And then in `HomeController` you put actions like these:

```
public ActionResult MyGallery(string username, int id) {
    // code
}

public ActionResult Profile(string username) {
    // code
}
```

EDIT: Of course, if the gallery ID is not an int, just use `string` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Mine should replace yours, plus you need the username in the action parameters, obviously. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look for [URL Rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) in ASP.NET to handle the dynamic parameters while routing.